# UILabel doesn't update after RaisePropertyChanged

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

### What I'm trying to achieve

I have a view, that has a picker, and a child view. When I change the value of the picker, some values from the child view should change.

### The problem

When I change the value of the picker, variables One and Two should get updated, but the changes don't show on the view.

### The code

I have a view where I bind a couple of properties, View.cs

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.tblCollection.TableFooterView = new UIView(CGRect.Empty);

        var source = new CollectionSource(this.tblCollection);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ItemView, ItemViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Item.ObsCollection);
        set.Bind(lblOne).To(vm => vm.Item.One);
        set.Bind(lblTwo).To(vm => vm.Item.Two);
        set.Bind(lblThree).To(vm => vm.Item.Three);
        set.Apply();

        this.tblCollection.Source = source;

        this.tblCollection.ReloadData();

    }
```

This view is inside another view, FatherView.cs, which has a picker

```
private void OnSyncFinished(SyncComplete obj)
    {
        this.InitPicker(this.PickerDiscount,
            this.btnDiscount,
            this.ViewModel.Discounts.Select(m => m.Desc).ToList(),
            "Discount");

        this.ViewModel.Discount = this.ViewModel.Discounts.FirstOrDefault();
    }


    void InitPicker(ModalPickerViewController picker, UIButton btn, List<string> list, string title)
    {
        if (picker == null)
        {
            picker = this.CreateCustomPicker(title, list, UIUtils.ColorGreen);
            picker.OnModalPickerDismissed += (sender, args) => this.OnElementSelected(picker);
            btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, args) => PresentViewControllerAsync(picker, true);
        }
        else
        {
            picker.PickerView.Model = new CustomPickerModel(list);
        }
    }

    void OnElementSelected(ModalPickerViewController picker)
    {
        var index = picker.PickerView.SelectedRowInComponent(0);
        var discount = this.ViewModel.Discounts[(int) index];
        this.ViewModel.DiscountSelected = discount;
    }
```

When I modify DiscountSelected

```
    private Discount discountSelected;
    public Discount DiscountSelected
    {
        get { return this.discountSelected; }
        set
        {
            this.discountSelected = value;
            this.OnDiscountSelected(this.discountSelected);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.DiscountSelected);
        }
    }
```

It goes to

```
public void OnDiscountSelected(Discount discount)
    {
        foreach (var item in ViewModelsCollection)
        {
            item.ItemSelected.Discount = discount.Total;
        }
    }
```

Which goes to this

```
private int discount;
[XmlIgnore]
public int Discount
{
    get
    {
        return this.discount;
    }
    set
    {
        this.descuento = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Discount);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.One);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Two);
    }
}
```

Where this.One and this.Two get updated. Like this

```
    private decimal one;
    public decimal One
    {
        get
        {
            var dto = this.one * this.Discount / 100;

            return this.one - dto;
        }
        set
        {
            this.one = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.One);
        }
    }

    private decimal two;
    public decimal Two
    {
        get
        {
            var dto = this.two * this.Discount / 100;

            return this.two - dto;
        }
        set
        {
            this.two = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Two);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What MVVM framework or Binding library are you using?

Comment: MvvmCross is the framework

Comment: @SantiagoQuiroga, from you code sample I do not seem anywhere where you are updating the values of properties One and Two. RaisePropertyChanged in your last code block will just raise a propertychanged event, but if the underlying values of One and Two have not changed then you will see no difference.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r I added the relevant code.